# Connecting a VGA monitor via Thunderbolt to a MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, vga

I have a MacBook Pro 13.3" with OSX 10.8.4, which I use mostly at home and at workplace to connect to external monitor.

At home, I have monitor with HDMI input and at my workplace with VGA input. I'm using a Thunderbolt MiniDisplay port to VGA and a Thunderbolt MiniDisplay port to HDMI cable convertors.

When I connect the monitor with the HDMI input at home it works perfectly and it connects quickly; that doesn't happen with the VGA monitor. When I connect it, the MacBook detects the monitor, but the monitor is not showing anything and goes to sleep mode.

Sometimes opening and closing my laptop helps, but not always.

After restarting the MacBook, I'm able to connect.

It's not comfortable to always restart the laptop, since I mostly leave it in sleep mode without closing applications. Does anyone have the same problem and found other solutions to this problem? How should I connect a VGA monitor without restarting the MacBook?

Comment: Have you tried to connect VGA first and thunderbolt to Mac at the latest? Or plug out and in the thunderbolt again?

What you describe happened to me when I plugged in thunderbolt first and VGA later.

Comment: I tried both ways, but it makes no sense.

Comment: Have you ruled out a defect in the monitor or the TB/VGA adapter?

Comment: There is no defect in adapter. It was system deffect, because after lastest update this problem is solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open System Preferences → Display.

Hold <kbd>⌥option</kbd> which will change the ‘Gather Windows’ button to ‘Detect Displays’.

Clicking it might detect your VGA.

Answer (score 0):

plugging thunderbolt into Mac last worked for me