# MacbookPro turns off while connecting to a projector via VGA (MBP 13" late 2016 without touchbar)

Tags: macbook-pro, display, vga-adapter, vga

I am using a MBP 13" late 2016 without touchbar. I use a CableMatters USB-C dongle to connect a VGA monitor to my laptop and it works.

However, when I connect an external projector to my MBP (I tested on two different projectors) using the same dongle

- there is a black screen on the laptop
- then in a few seconds, it says there is a problem in different languages and press any key to restart

Is there a problem with the dongle or the laptop? I am confused as the dongle works fine with a standard VGA monitor.

Comment: This answer may help: [Connecting a VGA monitor via Thunderbolt to a MacBook Pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/99193/120171)

Comment: Sorry, this answer is not related to my question, as my laptop really restarts when I connect to the VGA projector